# Pass 0 via URL as parameter

Tags: php

for some reason whenevever i try to pass 0 using a url parameter variable, on the other end it ends up as empty or null. How do i pass 0 from let's say page A to page B using url parameters?

In symfony
       `echo form_tag('application/recognition?step=0')?>`

ends up being like

`application/recognition`

and step is lost, however if 0 is changed to 1 it does work.

Thanks..

Comment: According to the symfony project site, Form Helpers (like `form_tag`) are deprecated, and instead plain HTML should be used. Is there a way for you to avoid using form_tag?

Comment: I will have to change about 9 pages using it , if that's the case. The problem is not form_tag, I think form_tag is using another function called tag() which i can't find any information about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you checking for 0?  It should be `$_GET['param'] === '0'`.

Comment: was just trying to print it out on the other end

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.  `echo $_GET['param'];` should output '0' if it is a 0.

Comment: @Matt S: unless it is interpreted as integer before being echoed, in which case it will display an empty string.

Comment: @MainMa: GET parameters are always returned as strings by PHP in the superglobal.

Comment: @Matt S: I know. I meant that the OP might manipulate the variable before echoing it.

Comment: @MattS PHP doesn't have an understanding of "string" or "int" it will treat it as either or based on situation. If we all remember our C, then it could be remotely possible the PHP is interpreting 0 as "false" which might be causing an issue.

Comment: @user1260028 That is incorrect. PHP will interpret / convert as needed, but it does know types and they can be checked.  `==` will coerce types while `===` won't. You can check and compare specific types in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Check your code, make sure your page does not have "empty[$_GET['step']]"

When step=0, in php, empty[$_GET['step']] will return true which means step=0 is equal to step is empty.

So, if you have "empty[$_GET['step']]", your php page does not work when step=0